# C++ Use the methods of vector with a struct

Tags: c++, vector, methods, struct

i would like to do a thing like this. can ou help me :) Thank you

```cpp
/* Example: */

struct Name
{
 const char *full_name;
 const char *name;
};

std::vector<Name> n = { {"Harry Potter", "Harry"}, {"Hermione Granger", "Hermione"} };

// The expressions below does not work

string::const_iterator b = n.begin();
string::const_iterator e = n.end();
int s = n.size();
// ...
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What are you trying to do? Please be more specific, it's unclear what the problem is

Comment: why are you not using `std::string`?

Comment: `string::const_iterator b = n.begin();` doesn't make sense. `n` is a `std::vector<Name>`, it has no connection to `string`

Comment: I can't use the methods, begin, end, etc... I have an error during compilation xD

Comment: 'is not possible to do something like this n.name.begin()  ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem mainly comes from the :

```
 string::const_iterator b = n.begin(); // not possible
 string::const_iterator e = n.end(); // not possible
 int s = n.size(); // working as intended if you print it to the console
```

If you want to declare an iterator, in this case, you could do :

```
std::vector<Name>::const_iterator it;
```

If you would like to have control with the iterator, use it in a for loop :

```
for (it = n.begin(); it != n.end() - 1; it++) // Will stop at the first name in our example
{
    std::cout << it->full_name << std::endl;
}
```

As it is pointing to n, in order to access its values, don't forget to use ->.

If you wanted to iterate through the whole vector, it is possible to use a simple loop.`

```
for (auto i: n)
    {
        std::cout << "My name is " << i.name << ", ";
        std::cout << i.full_name << std::endl;
    }`
```

On a side note, you did not need to declare "it" before it was used in the for loop.
The following would work too :

```
for (auto it = n.begin(); it != n.end() - 1; it++) // Will stop at the first name in our example 
{
    std::cout << it->full_name << std::endl;
}
```

For reference, here is my final code with examples, I hope that solves your problem :

```
  struct Name
{
     std::string full_name;
     std::string name;
};


int main()
{
     std::vector<Name> n = { {"Harry Potter", "Harry"}, {"Hermione Granger", "Hermione"} }; 

     std::vector<Name>::const_iterator it;
    for (auto i : n) // Printing the whole vector
    {
        std::cout << "My name is " << i.name << ", ";
        std::cout << i.full_name << std::endl;
    }

    for (it = n.begin(); it != n.end() - 1; it++) // will return all the names except the last
    {
        std::cout << it->full_name << std::endl;

    }

    for (auto g = n.begin(); g != n.end() - 1; g++) // same as it, iterator initialized in the loop
    {
        std::cout << g->full_name << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```